# What is the platform tag to download packages for windows x86 64 using pip?

Tags: python, installation, pip, download

I need to download a package to my Mac to transfer and install it on an offline PC.

I am trying to do:

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 39 --abi cp39 --platform winx86-64 opencv-python numpy matplotlib
```

But that's obviously the wrong platform tag. How do I find out which one to take??

Comment: It's `win_amd64`.

Comment: Thank you! Can I download the dependencies as well some how? Currently only this works: `pip download --platform win-amd64 --no-deps numpy matplotlib opencv-python`

Comment: I don't have Windows, but if any of the dependencies doesn't provide a wheel file matching the constraints, `pip download` will resort to the source distribution and those are prohibited by `--only-binary=:all:` (I know it is required if you specify any platform-specific restrictions). Overall, `pip download` is messy and has issues, thus I don't like it.

Comment: What is the error message you get when running `pip download` from your question? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Hi, I went to a different windows computer with internet access and downloaded the packages from there... but for the record, I got this error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy`

Comment: Hmm, probably some cached package pins `numpy` to a version older than 1.19.3, so no 3.9 wheels are found. You can debug this by running `pip download -vvv ...` which prints the version resolution logs, providing reasoning for filtering out specific versions.

Comment: Or maybe this is because you tried to download wheels for windows platform on MacOS - I also recall having problems with `pip download` command not finding wheels, since it uses current platform instead of the one passed via `--platform` arg.